# WPF NavigationService is null

Tags: c#, wpf, navigationservice

I'm learning WPF (moving from Procedural PHP) and have written the following to navigate from 'MainWindow' to 'Page1', where there are no errors with the login credentials, but the local variable 'nav' is always null (hence displaying an error message):

```
namespace YM_POS_20160229_0949
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void ClickLoginSubmitButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            // Dictionary object is c# equivalent of PHP's 'array["key"] = "value"'
            Dictionary<string, string> errMsg = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            // declare variables
            string varUserName;
            string varUserPass;

            // define the variables whilst trimming the values passed
            varUserName = LoginUsername.Text.Trim();
            varUserPass = LoginPassword.Password.Trim();

            // ensure something has been submitted & perform validation on the values submitted

            // if there are no errors, navigate to the users dashboard (aka Page1)
            NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(new Page1());

            // check if the nav variable is populated
            if (nav != null)
            { 
                nav.Navigate(nav);
            }
            else
            {
                // display an error message to the user advising them an error has occurred and Page1 is not available
                MessageBox.Show("An error has occured.  unable to proceed to " + nav);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Newbie Matt

//UI / XAML

```
<Window x:Class="YM_POS_20160229_0949.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YM_POS_20160229_0949"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <DockPanel>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="123*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="394*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox x:Name="LoginUsername" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="56.649,55,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <PasswordBox x:Name="LoginPassword" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="56.649,100,0,0" Password="Password" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.Column="1" />
                <Button x:Name="LoginSubmitButton" Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="81.649,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"  Click="ClickLoginSubmitButton" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: where are you displaying the Page1?

Comment: Doesn't it display in MainWindow - that's where the UN & Pwd values are coming from.  Sounds like I'm missing something?

Comment: Why dont you post your UI code

Comment: Offtopic: *If* I ever use your application, i'm going to give myself a password that ends with a whitespace character.